# Why does TypeScript think that my immer draft is undefined?

Tags: typescript

This makes no sense to me, please help:

I'm updating a typed config.

In my Provider component:

```
const [data, setData] = useImmer<typeof INITIAL_CONFIG>(INITIAL_CONFIG)
...
function updateField(field: MyConfigKeys, value: MyConfigValues): void 
  setData(draft => {
    draft[field] = value 
  })
}
```

error:

```
(parameter) draft: WritableDraft<Partial<MyConfigType>>
Type 'MyConfigValues' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.ts(2322)
```

What is going on???

Here's a sandbox with a minimal reproducible example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-keldysh-kxvckq?file=/src/App.tsx
(there the error is never, instead of undefined):

Comment: You set the type of `data` to `typeof INITIAL_CONFIG`, which probably has a field that was given `undefined`...

Comment: It would help if we could see what `INITIAL_CONFIG` is, and if you could, it would be greatly beneficial if you could create a minimal reproducible example (preferably as an official TS playground).

Comment: @caTS My initial config is a partial of a config with all properties typed to either enums, boolean, strings, or numbers. When I remove the partial, I still get the same error. 

And, even when I wrap my update in a conditional check (if(draft[field] !== undfined) {setData...} same thing.

Comment: @caTS Oddly enough in my minimal reproducible example - https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-keldysh-kxvckq?file=/src/App.tsx it's  throwing a "never", rather than undefined.
I'd be happy to use the TS playground, but I"m not sure if I can use it with React? Please let me know if you prefer that over sandbox

Comment: You actually can: https://tsplay.dev/weQjYw - the playground attempts to import any modules found on the registry. However, you can't run the code if you do import any of them, but you will get the types.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that TS does not know that the value should match with the field. You can fix this by making it generic:

```
function updateField<K extends MyConfigKeys>(field: K, value: MyConfigType[K]): void {
    setData((draft) => {
      draft[field] = value;
    });
  }
```

Now TS knows that `value` should match the `field`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/weQjYw)